# Best way to clear a UITextField

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, uitextfield

For an `IBOutlet UITextField`, does it matter as far as memory management or other reasons how you clear the text value?

```
textFieldX.text = nil
```

or

```
textFieldX.text = @"";
```

In objective-c it is acceptable to message a `nil` object and `@""` is a static `NSString *`. I'm not sure if every `@""` points to the same object in memory or if it allocates a bunch of 1 byte null terminated strings.

Not a big deal, just thought I'd ask the community. Thanks.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Personally I would think less of the memory usage here and more on code-maintainability.

To me, It makes sense that a label always has a string.  In the future someone might try to append a labels value, save it in a database, wrap it in xml, etc.  An empty NSString in this case makes much more sense to me that a 0x0.

Comment: All responses are great, thanks. This is a good point here, though. Code consistency. Thanks all.

Answer (score 11):

I usually do `textFieldX.text = @"";` just for clarity.  This helps me remember that the value should be a string, and that I can pass it all the standard string methods.

Comment: Does this make the placeholder string reappear?

Comment: I can confirm that it does, @Supertecnoboff

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you to use nil, because I discovered that when you use @"", the placeholder is not aligned in the center(if it must be aligned). Look, how I changed my code to get placeholder aligned properly.

```
 wordTextField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
 //wordTextField.text = @"";
 wordTextField.text = nil;
 translationTextField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
 //translationTextField.text = @"";
 translationTextField.text = nil;
```

Answer (score 2):

Strings always copy in Objective-C, so the second option is most likely creating another string, and then pointing to it.  In that way, I think you're right.

To play devil's advocate, I would assume that the compiler optimizes option B to do something like option A anyway.  Personally, I would always do option B because it's more readable as far as the end operation you want to accomplish.

UPDATE: I didn't find a way to accomplish your goal differently, but you may be interested in this tidbit (from [Apple UITextField Docs](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/clearButtonMode)):

> clearButtonMode
>
> Controls when the standard clear
>   button appears in the text field.
>
> @property(nonatomic)
>   UITextFieldViewMode clearButtonMode
>
> Discussion
>
> The standard clear button is displayed
>   at the right side of the text field as
>   a way for the user to remove text
>   quickly. This button appears
>   automatically based on the value set
>   for this property.
>
> The default value for this property is
>   UITextFieldViewModeNever.

I think this would allow you to setup functionality for the user to clear the text field.

Comment: I'm speaking more toward clearing the text programmatically on viewWillAppear for editing objects, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I find that using `textField.text = nil;` has an undesirable effect on my project. I am building a calculator.

When using the above code, after I press the clear button, pressing a digit does not come up on screen.

```
textField.text = @"";
```

works good for me.

Answer (score -1):

To get undo/redo support, you can implement like this

```swift
// [Public]
textField.selectAll(nil)
if let range = textField.selectedTextRange {
  textField.replace(range, withText: "")
}

// [Private]
let _fieldEditor: AnyObject = textField.perform(Selector(("_fieldEditor"))).takeRetainedValue()
let _inputController: AnyObject = _fieldEditor.perform(Selector(("_inputController"))).takeRetainedValue()
_ = _inputController.perform(Selector(("clearText"))).takeUnretainedValue()
```

Comment: What does the code have to do with undo/redo support? Why the really strange code for clearing the text field?

Comment: The setText: method resets the NSUndoManager's undo stack, but UITextInput methods (such as 'insert' and 'replace') do not reset the undo stack. If you see the implementation of UITextField's clear button (-[UITextField _clearButtonClicked:]), you will find it has similar code behavior. Just try it. You can see the difference.